# shopify customer and order transfer into magento

Tags: magento, shopify

I want real time customer and order migrate into Magento from Shopify.

Suppose that if any order and customer create into Shopify. That we migrate into Magento on real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Setup webhooks in your Shopify store to send orders to your URI endpoint. With that data, parse it out and map it to Magento format, and insert the mapped data to your Magento store.